# Output probabilities of tokens generated by Llama 2 using Transformers

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, llama

Given input tokens, LLMs output the tokens in their vocabulary that have the highest probability of coming after the input tokens.

I would like to print the probability of each token generated by the model in response to a prompt to see how confident the model is in its generated tokens. I would like to do this on Llama-2-7b-chat-hf on a simple prompt like : "Could you give me 3 cities located in Europe ?".

In order to do this I have the following code :

```
from transformers import LlamaForCausalLM, LlamaTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
import torch
import numpy as np

device = "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

model=LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained("Llama-2-7b-chat-hf").to(device)
tokenizer= LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained("Llama-2-7b-chat-hf")

prompt = "Could you give me 3 cities located in Europe ?"

inputs = tokenizer([prompt], return_tensors="pt").to(device)

outputs=model.generate(**inputs,return_dict_in_generate=True, output_scores=True,max_new_tokens=75)

transition_scores = model.compute_transition_scores(outputs.sequences, outputs.scores, normalize_logits=True)

input_length = 1 if model.config.is_encoder_decoder else inputs.input_ids.shape[1]
generated_tokens = outputs.sequences[:,input_length:]

for tok, score in zip(generated_tokens[0], transition_scores[0]):
        # | token | token string | logits | probability
            print(f"| {tok:5d} | {tokenizer.decode(tok):8s} | {score.numpy(force=True):.4f} | {np.exp(score.numpy(force=True)):.2%}")
```

As a result I receive the following :

```
| token | token string | logits | probability
|    13 | <0x0A>   | 0.0000 | 100.00%
|    13 | <0x0A>   | 0.0000 | 100.00%
| 10605 | Here     | -3.0267 | 4.85%
|   526 | are      | 0.0000 | 100.00%
| 29871 |          | -0.3506 | 70.43%
| 29941 | 3        | 0.0000 | 100.00%
| 14368 | cities   | 0.0000 | 100.00%
|  5982 | located  | 0.0000 | 100.00%
|   297 | in       | 0.0000 | 100.00%
|  4092 | Europe   | 0.0000 | 100.00%
| 29901 | :        | 0.0000 | 100.00%
|    13 | <0x0A>   | 0.0000 | 100.00%
|    13 | <0x0A>   | 0.0000 | 100.00%
| 29896 | 1        | 0.0000 | 100.00%
| 29889 | .        | 0.0000 | 100.00%
|  3681 | Paris    | 0.0000 | 100.00%
| 29892 | ,        | 0.0000 | 100.00%
|  3444 | France   | 0.0000 | 100.00%
|    13 | <0x0A>   | 0.0000 | 100.00%
| 29906 | 2        | 0.0000 | 100.00%
| 29889 | .        | 0.0000 | 100.00%
|  9184 | Rome     | -1.0413 | 35.30%
| 29892 | ,        | 0.0000 | 100.00%
| 12730 | Italy    | 0.0000 | 100.00%
|    13 | <0x0A>   | 0.0000 | 100.00%
| 29941 | 3        | 0.0000 | 100.00%
| 29889 | .        | 0.0000 | 100.00%
|  4517 | London   | 0.0000 | 100.00%
| 29892 | ,        | 0.0000 | 100.00%
|  3303 | United   | 0.0000 | 100.00%
| 12626 | Kingdom  | 0.0000 | 100.00%
|     2 | </s>     | 0.0000 | 100.00%
```

As you can see, most of the words have a probability of 100% of being chosen which seems very odd to me. Llama 2 has a vocabulary of 32000 tokens surely there are other tokens that could be used at the place of those tokens, I would agree with something like 70% but 100% should be impossible. Which makes me believe something is wrong in my code.

Would you agree with me ? And if yes, would you know what is wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Could be due to

1. **Temperature parameter** (most likely): if it is set **close to 0**, you basically just focus on the most probable token, which gets 100% of the probability mass. (Check the Softmax with temperature). Increase the temperature and you will get a more uniform distribution and a more "creative" response.
2. In an extreme case, if the **top-k** **is set to 1**, it would always select the most probable token. With normalize_logits=True, this token would then be assigned a probability of 100%.